# No "Try it out" button for HEAD method in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Swagger spec that defines a HEAD operation:

```
head:
  description: show flight exist or not.

  parameters:
    - name: flight_no
      in: path
      type: string
      description: Flight_no
      required: true
  produces:
    - application/json
    - application/xml

  responses:
    200:
      description: success response
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Data'
    '404':
      description: flight does not exist
```

In Swagger UI v. 2, this HEAD operation has no "try it out" button. How can I add "try it out" for HEAD?

[image: HEAD operation in Swagger UI]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try Swagger UI 3.0 – HEAD has "try it out" by default in this version.

If you use Swagger UI 2.0, HEAD is disabled by default. You need to explicitly enable it in the `supportedSubmitMethods` list in the Swagger UI initialization code in index.html:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
  url: url,
  dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
  supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch', 'head'],
  //                                                                   ^
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------┘
```

By the way, `schema` in a HEAD response is not really useful because HEAD is not supposed to return an actual body – only the headers. You should change the 200 response to:

```
responses:
  200:
    description: success response
```

Answer (score 2):

to add up, in java you can add a [bean](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2340) in your swagger config class to do that:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig { 
                               
    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
      return new UiConfiguration(null, UiConfiguration.Constants.NO_SUBMIT_METHODS);
    }
}
```

Basically it will put `supportedSubmitMethods` to `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS by "head" value.

```
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfig  {

        @Bean
        UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
            return new UiConfiguration( null, new String[] {"get", "post", "put", "delete", "patch", "head"} );
        }
    }
```